# asp.net gridview editing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview (Edit and Delete enabled) that shows a table. A Text Box and A Button. When I type something in the textbox and click the button, the button runs the datasource.filterexpression and filters out the rows.

The question whenever I click on the edit button after the filter has been applied The grid auto resets back to the original table? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After saving the edited record in the GridView RowUpdating event, re-apply the filter and call DataBind()